# JQuery Calculate DIV width in pixels

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to get the actual `width` of an arbitrary `DIV` in `pixels` using `JQuery` w/out plugins? I'm interested in the following two scenarios:

1. DIV's width specified in `percents`, I need to walk up the tree remembering paddings and/or margins, find the first parents with the width in pixels and then walk down to my element applying those paddings and margins.
2. DIV is positioned `absolutely` using `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left` `CSS` attributes, kind similar to the previous one, just to need to take these attributes into account.

A simple call for a DIV with `width: 100%;` returns `100`, which isn't good enough for me.

**Update 1 - the control, which width I measured was hidden at the time when I call control.width(), that's it really.**

Comment: 1) show what you have tried.  2) a google search for `jquery element width` returned 8,270,000 possible solutions and the first one is a link to the jquery API `.width()`

Comment: did you just go to one of my answers and voted it down just for revenge? and left a comment?? come on!!!

Answer (score 4):

if `width()` doesn't work as expected (a fiddle would help) use `offsetWidth`. Assuming you've a jQuery reference to the element

```
$('div').get(0).offsetWidth;
```

will return the width of the element in pixel

Comment: Hm... But what's the problem with `$("div").width()`?

Comment: I just suggested an alternative, assuming that OP had some issue with jQuery methods. A fiddle with the real problem would help

Comment: The problem with $("div").width() in my case was that if the div is set in % it would return % and I want px. Using $('div').get(0).offsetWidth solved it. Getting div width in pixels solved :)

Answer (score 1):

It working as expected check [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TDkLH/)

```
alert($('div').width());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
 $(function () {
        alert($("#YourDivIdHere").css("width"))
 })
```